# Renaming columns in Pandas DataFrame not working

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I created a Pandas DataFrame which has column names 0,1,2.. and am trying to rename them, but the rename function is not working.

my code:

complete_list is a list of lists, which i would like to convert to csv.

```
output_csv = pd.DataFrame(complete_list) 
output_csv.rename(columns={'0':'dpinID', '1': 'latin_name', '2': 'common_names'})
output_csv.to_csv('output.csv')
```

[this is the head of the dataframe complete_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkyQt.png)

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Add `inplace=True` in your `.rename(...)`

Comment: i have tried this already. it does not change anything in my case.

Comment: What does `output_csv.columns` look like?

Comment: the output is ```Int64Index([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...272], dtype='int64', length=273)```

Comment: The column names are `int`s, but you have them as `str`s in your renamer. I have a feeling that's what's causing the issue. Try `.rename(columns={0:'dpinID', 1: 'latin_name', 2: 'common_names'}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 3):

The problems you face are caused by two issues:

1. `.rename(...)` returns a new DataFrame, rather than altering the existing dataframe in-place
2. The renaming dictionary uses stringified integers for the source names, instead of the actual `int` value

The fix is rather simple:

```
output_csv.rename(columns={0:'dpinID', 1: 'latin_name', 2: 'common_names'}, inplace=True)
```